# Docker container Ubuntu SSH access

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh

I installed a new docker container (the standard Ubuntu latest version).
I would like connect on it trough SSH access. I followed instructions on this excellent link https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-connect-to-docker-container-via-ssh

Once I stop my container and restart it, SSH service is not available anymore.
I have to start it manually anytime.
I tried this command too "systemctl enable ssh" to configure ssh as permanent.
The result is as followed:

"Synchronizing state of ssh.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ssh"

So everything seems be ok, but when I stop the container and restart it, the problem is still present, no ssh service started on the ubuntu.

Someone knows how to configure SSH access as permanent on this case?

Thank you all by advance for your help :)

Comment: Usually a Docker container wraps a single process; for example, an Nginx or PostgreSQL server.  The single process usually isn't an ssh daemon and getting an interactive shell inside the process usually isn't an important task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a customized Dockerfile, and inside it instrument the SSH configuration so, each time you run the container, it will have a working SSH daemon.

About the issue that when you rerun the container it loses the SSH configuration is caused by the fact that you a craeting a new container from the original (non SSH configured) Ubuntu image. If you want to run the configured container you have to get the containers lsit by `docker container ls --all' and copy the ID, the run the container by` docker run {{ID}}`.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer :). I will try that.

Comment: Please accept and upvote if my answer will suite for you. Thank you.